# Import project from bitbucket to local maven repository

Tags: java, maven, bitbucket

I have a maven project in bitbucket account. I need to add that the project in my local maven repository so that I can refer that project as a maven dependency in my main project's pom.xml.

That is, perform below steps

1) Clone the project
2) run `maven build install` This will add to local maven repository

Please let me know if there is a way to achieve the same (in similar ways to connecting to maven public repository) ?

Comment: You want to integrate maven with your git repo ? Then maybe you have to follow the Maven SCM [example](https://maven.apache.org/scm/maven-scm-plugin/usage.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by defining repositories in pom file of the project where you want to use project 1 as a dependency.

For eg.

Git clone path of Project 1: https://github.com/yogi21jan/project1

Add below code in child project:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>YOUR-PROJECT-NAME-mvn-repo</id>
        <url>https://raw.github.com/YOUR-USERNAME/YOUR-PROJECT-NAME/mvn-repo/</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

And finally Add this project as a dependency:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>group id of project 1</groupId>
     <artifactId>artifcat id of project 1</artifactId>
     <version>required version</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look  into [jitpack.io](https://jitpack.io). It can create a Maven repository for a GitHub project and also other hosters like [BitBucket, GitLab, Azure, Gitee](https://github.com/jitpack/jitpack.io/#other-git-hosts).

I have choosen a random Maven based project,
here [fastconverter](https://bitbucket.org/karelik/fastconvertor/src/master/). It not GitHub is used, the full URL has to be provided. The created jar is published then [here](https://jitpack.io/#karelik/fastconvertor/master-06014b14e2-1).